How to remove a specific pages from the site map in WordPress?
I want to eliminate some links and articles from the sitemap page. I have tried using a plugin called "WordPress Simple HTML Sitemap" and even tried from within WordPress itself but haven't been successful.
Is there a free, effective plugin or another method to do this?
My last resort is to apply CSS {display: none} to those pages using the inspector, but I want a better solution.
I have tried using the third party plugins.

To do it without a plugin, use the wp_sitemaps_posts_query_args hook, setting the post__not_in argument. Add this code to functions.php:
add_filter('wp_sitemaps_posts_query_args', function($args, $post_type) {

  // for post types other than pages, exit without doing any customisation
  if ('page' !== $post_type) return $args;

  // set the page IDs to exclude
  $args['post__not_in'] = array(111, 222, 333);
  return $args;

}, 10, 2);

